# AWS idle sesstion timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services

For non-federated accounts, we'd like to set an idle session timeout.  As I understand it, this is set in IAM and can be seen in a role's “summary” section and also edited there.

What is the enforcement mechanism?  We have users who can access resources past the duration limit.  What are any other settings to enforce idle session timeout?

Comment: How are they accessing AWS? Via the console, or via CLI/API?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein... both... Console and API.